# Mesh hair does not properly follow head

Tags: mesh, armature, hair, parent

[image: mesh hair not deforming to head]

Hello, this is a problem I have had since I've started using Blender (2.82). The model was imported from Makehuman. If I use hair from Makehuman, no problems. If I create a hair mesh, it never follows the head properly. I have tried every form of parenting. Messed around with weight paints, constraints and vertex groups. Watched tons of tutorials, read dozens of posts and "Blender for Dummies". Nothing works. (the braid doesn't follow the braid bones properly either.)
I have created several different meshes with different Makehuman rig types but the result was always the same. It shouldn't be this difficult to do something so basic as sticking hair on a head. I can't help thinking that I'm missing something obvious but I don't know what it is. I would have uploaded the file but I didn't see where to do that. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have since discovered a two step method that seems to work. (Whether it's the best method is another matter.) I parent the hair mesh to the armature with empty groups. Select the model mesh, then shift select the hair mesh. Go into weight paint mode and transfer weights, selection: by name. Wa-La. It works, but then the hair mesh picks up all of the model's vertex groups.

Comment: and you'll find that in most of these groups the weight of all vertices is zero (e.g., feet and lower extremities).  One could write a python script to find and delete these... alas there's no built-in command to clean this up.